# Comparing a bunch of files on different folders

Tags: files, file-comparison

I have two folders with 200 txt files each, all files named like `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, etc., on both folders.

Is there a way to use one command to compare file1 in both folders, file2 in both folders, etc., and list if they are the same or not? I just want to know which files are the same or not, not the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-q` option to `diff` makes it only list the names of files with differences (or missing from one of the directories):

```
diff -q folder1 folder2
```

Comment: simply P E R F E C T!!!!!!